# arduino 16u2 stk500v2_command(): command failed

Tags: avr, avrdude

I'm trying to fix arduino uno r3 that was burned-out.
I changed m16u2 chip on it. and now I need burn in:  `Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex`
I'm using stk500v2 and connecting it to isp of arduino. Output log file of avrdude:

```
C:\>avrdude -c stk500v2 -P COM4 -p m16u2 -U flash:w:1.hex -vvvv

avrdude: Version 6.1, compiled on Mar 13 2014 at 00:09:49
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude.conf"


         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : stk500v2
avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [01] . [00] . [01] . [0e] . [01] . [14]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [01]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [0b]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [01]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [08]
avrdude: Recv: A [41]
avrdude: Recv: V [56]
avrdude: Recv: R [52]
avrdude: Recv: I [49]
avrdude: Recv: S [53]
avrdude: Recv: P [50]
avrdude: Recv: _ [5f]
avrdude: Recv: 2 [32]
avrdude: Recv: t [74]
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): found AVRISP programmer
         AVR Part                      : ATmega16U2
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC6
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no        512    4    128  9000  90
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     16384  128    128  4500  45
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  90
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  90
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  90
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  90
00 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0
 0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page
      Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  Max
W   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ---
-- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0
 0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500V2
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 2.x firmware
         Programmer Model: AVRISP
avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [02] . [00] . [02] . [0e] . [03] . [90] . [86]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [02]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [02]
avrdude: Recv: . [15]
avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [03] . [00] . [02] . [0e] . [03] . [91] . [86]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [02]
avrdude: Recv: . [14]
avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [04] . [00] . [02] . [0e] . [03] . [92] . [82]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [04]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [0a]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version Master : 2.10
avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [05] . [00] . [02] . [0e] . [03] . [94] . [85]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [05]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [03]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: U [55]
avrdude: Recv: E [45]
         Vtarget         : 8.5 V
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [06] . [00] . [0c] . [0e] . [10] . [c8] d [64] . [19]
[20] . [00] S [53] . [03] . [ac] S [53] . [00] . [00] 5 [35]
avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
avrdude: Recv: . [06]
avrdude: Recv: . [00]
avrdude: Recv: . [02]
avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
avrdude: Recv: . [10]
avrdude: Recv: . [c0]
avrdude: Recv: . [c1]
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

    avrdude: Send: . [1b] . [07] . [00] . [03] . [0e] . [11] . [01] . [01] . [00]
    avrdude: Recv: . [1b]
    avrdude: Recv: . [07]
    avrdude: Recv: . [00]
    avrdude: Recv: . [02]
    avrdude: Recv: . [0e]
    avrdude: Recv: . [11]
    avrdude: Recv: . [00]
    avrdude: Recv: . [01]

    avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

My question is what block with error does? can it be I shorted due soldering? or maybe burned chip? any issues? how I can check?

ps. programmer works perfect. checked!

Comment: All I can tell from this log is that communication with the MCU does not work at all, i.e. it fails on the very first command sent to it (all the preceding communication is with the controller). 

There could be numerous causes for this (chip rotated by 90 degrees, etc). I would start by attaching a logic analyzer to the MISO pin and see whether there are any wiggles there at all.

Comment: One important question to be sure: Arduino UNO has 2 ISP connectors, one for the ATmega328, and one for ATmega16u2 (used for USB connection); are you sure you are connecting to the 2nd one?

Comment: yes i'm sure. its connected to ATmega16u2. @microtherion does the sended bits and received bits must be same?

Comment: @Klasik it’s a bit beyond the scope of a comment to explain, so I’ve made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a decoding of the crucial pair of messages exchanged here. Protocol is documented [on Atmel’s site](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2591.pdf).

Your machine sends:

```
[1b]                              Beginning of message
[06]                              Message sequence number
[00] [0c]                         Message body length (big endian)
[0e]                              Beginning of message body
[10]                              Command: CMD_ENTER_PROGMODE_ISP 
[c8] [64] [19] [20] [00]          Various programming parameters
[53]                              Response value to look for
[03]                              Response index 
[ac] [53] [00] [00]               Enter programming mode command
[35]                              Checksum
```

This causes the programmer to send the 4 bytes `0xAC 0x53 0x00 0x00` to the MCU, and look for the value `0x53` in the third of the 4 response bytes, as specified on page 260 of the [data sheet](http://www.atmel.ch/Images/doc7799.pdf). However, the programmer answers:

```
[1b]                              Beginning of message
[06]                              Sequence number (matches message previously sent)
[00] [02]                         Response body length
[0e]                              Beginning of response body
[10]                              Command: CMD_ENTER_PROGMODE_ISP (Matches message)
[c0]                              STATUS_CMD_FAILED (This is the error message)
[c1]                              Checksum
```

That means that tyne very first command sent to the microcontroller “failed” (most likely by not returning the expected answer byte).

Comment: is it called post code or something?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question, @Klasik.

Comment: how thous codes called? )

Comment: Btw. the solution was resoldering SMD.